# Postgresql UPDATE syntax error on RAISE exception in CASE / IF condition

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, sqlexception

I am confused with writing Postgresql UPDATE query with CASE (or IF) condition.

**Expected behavior:** I have to raise an exception and do not do update if one specific field is not null. 
**Current behavior:** I tries CASE and IF conditions, but every time I got syntax error: SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "exception".
**Thoughts**: maybe there is a way to achieve same result with adding constraint to table?

```
    UPDATE public.SomeTable 
SET Title = (
    case when EndDate IS null
        THEN 'new title' 
        ELSE raise exception 'Cannot update entity if EndDate is not null'
    end),
    Description = (
    case when EndDate IS null
        THEN 'new description' 
        ELSE raise exception 'Cannot update entity if EndDate is not null'
    end)
WHERE Id=4
```

*Version:*
PostgreSQL 11.5 (Debian 11.5-1.pgdg90+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u1) 6.3.0 20170516, 64-bit

Comment: You can't use `RAISE` inside a SQL query. It's a PL/pgSQL statement that can only be used "standalone"

Comment: I think you need to do this with a trigger.

Comment: Note: RAISE affects (rolls back) the complete tranaction. You cannot RAISE on a per-row basis.

Answer (score 1):

The only relatively convenient way I can think to do this uses updatable views:

```
create view vw_sometable as
    select t.*
    from sometable t
    where endDate is null
    with check option;
```

You would then insert into the view, rather than into the underlying table.

You can further refine this by giving `update` permissions on the view but not on the underlying table, so all `update`s need to go through the view.

Well, another method would not return an error, but it would not update the rows.  Just include the condition in the `where` clause:

```
UPDATE public.SomeTable 
    SET Title = 'new title',
        Description = 'new description' 
WHERE Id = 4 AND EndDate is null';
```

You could add subsequent logic to check if any rows are updated and raise the error there.

Answer (score 0):

remove case after end

```
UPDATE public.SomeTable 
SET Title = (
    case when EndDate IS null
        THEN 'new title' 
        ELSE 'Cannot update entity if EndDate is not null'
    end ),
    Description = (
    case when EndDate IS null
        THEN 'new description' 
        ELSE 'Cannot update entity if EndDate is not null'
    end )
WHERE Id=4
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but that does'nt solve the issue

Comment: hm, this means that in case when EndDate would be not null, Fields will be updated with 'Cannot update entity if EndDate is not null' string. That is the opposite what I need. I 'd like to throw some error in this case